# CSS Code max-width not working when published on the Internet

Tags: html, css, width

I've been dealing with a problem for too long now regarding my CSS code. It's linked in the HTML-file and everything but the max-width works when I publish it on the Internet. The max-width is correct when I open the file from my desktop-file, but when I go the www-file on the Internet the max-width does not stick and the div #content is larger and expands when the page expands which I do not want. I want it to stay 600px wide.

The div is:
`#content
{ background-color: black;
max-width: 600px;
padding: 20px; }`

and it is referenced in the HTML: 
`<div id="content">`

Why is this max-width only working when I open the file from my desktop and not when published on the Internet? Driving me crazy.

Thankful for help!

Comment: Can you try a different browser? Possibly FireFox without caching enabled.

Comment: add width: 100%

Comment: Probably try opening it with the "width" property on localhost..

Comment: Tried both Safari and Google Crome... And it doesn't help by adding max-width: 100%...

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and set max-height to 100%...
It may solve out...
you can also keep height to auto and width to the max limit...
Check a live example of mine:- [escot](https://obnoxiousnerd.github.io/escot)

Comment: What does this code do? Quite new with coding... Also, the max-width: 100% doesn't help unfortunately...

Comment: Not max-wdith: 100%, just width:100%.

Comment: The thing is I just want the #content div (a black background) to be 600px wide on the page. When I open the file from my desktop files it works, but on the internet it doesn't stay 600px wide, it becomes bigger and is full size over the page.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">` in your head tag. also i would at your `<div id="mainBody">` that you would use at the top of your body, right after the body. once you style that `<div>` tag use this code as a sample of what should be done.

```
.mainBody {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: white;
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 580px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
```

hope this helps!